# error vegan rarecurve Error in as(x, "matrix")[i, j, drop = FALSE] : (subscript) logical subscript too long

Tags: r, vegan, phyloseq

I am trying to plot some rarefaction curves, but I am getting this error:

```
Error in as(x, "matrix")[i, j, drop = FALSE] :  (subscript) logical subscript too long
```

I am giving a reproducible example on how I use the function:

```
 data("GlobalPatterns")
rare<-rarecurve(otu_table(GlobalPatterns), step=100, lwd=2, ylab="OTU", label=F)
```

I am using R.4.2.2 and version 2.6-4 of vegan.
I already used this function with the phyloseq object like this and it worked properly,
Do you know what is the problem and how I could fix it?

Answer (score 4):

It seems to be that **phyloseq** package does not support this analysis. A way to circumvent these problems is to take care that `phyloseq::otu_table` returns a normal **R** matrix. Further, the data you used is transposed to the **vegan** standard (your data have OTU as rows, whereas they should be columns in **vegan** standards: observations are rows).

```
library(phyloseq)
data("GlobalPatterns")
tab <- otu_table(GlobalPatterns)
class(tab) <- "matrix" # as.matrix() will do nothing
## you get a warning here, but this is what we need to have
tab <- t(tab) # transpose observations to rows
library(vegan)
rare <- rarecurve(tab, step=10000, lwd=2, ylab="OTU",  label=F)
```

Technically the error is that `otu_table` does not allow long logical index. This is an internal issue of the **phyloseq** implementation, and I won't delve into innards of **phyloseq** to find the reason. However, standard **R** matrix works, but **R** does not know that `otu_table` only fakes being a matrix. Therefore the violent way of forcing `otu_table` to a matrix.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation, I recently updated phyloseq and since then I am getting this error...I will use the solution you gave me!